# Can you use Favored Foe multiple times on the same creature?

Tags: dnd-5e, attack, ranger, alternate-class-feature

In D&D 5e (Tasha's Cauldron of Everything), if I hit a creature and use the [Favored Foe](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/ranger#OptionalClassFeatures) feature to mark it and deal additional damage, would I be able to stop concentrating on the initial mark and then use Favored Foe again to mark the same creature, dealing the additional damage once more, if I hit it with another attack and have remaining uses of Favored Foe? I'm specifically referring to doing that in just one turn.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take a look at the [tour] and visit the [help] in case you need any help! Happy gaming!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### No, it works just once per turn.

The description of the feature says (emphasis mine):

> **The first time on each of your turns** that you hit the favored enemy and deal damage to it, including when you mark it, you can increase that damage by 1d4.

So, even if you stop concentrating on it and you have more than one attack, the second attack that hits your target *on the same turn* will not deal the bonus damage if you "reactivate" Favored Foe. It works only on the first landed attack on each of your turns.